# HTML text elements have padding that isn't consistent between browsers after setting padding to 0

Tags: html, css, text, fonts, padding

I've given the elements a border so that you can see the inconsistent padding. The only thing I have added is a padding-left to each of the 3 elements. I'm trying to space the headlines vertically with even space between across different browsers. Can't figure it out.

Here is how it looks in Chrome:
http://postimage.org/image/ly5gzp0k5/

Here is how it looks in IE:
http://postimage.org/image/qa34t76al/

All padding top and bottom is set to zero. In fact, all css is reset to my knowledge and after hours of trying to figure it out, I decided to post on Stack Overflow hoping for any help someone could provide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be possible to answer your question if you add your code for example using jsfiddle.net

Comment: It's most likely a difference in line-height.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `line-height` to positioning your text vertically. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4c35L/) is some example for how to use it.

Comment: I've messed around with line-height already to no avail. Here is a jsfiddle. If you view it in IE and then Chrome, you will see slightly more space below the "EXCITING" in IE. http://jsfiddle.net/87p5K/4/

Comment: Yes your right. It's becouse your styles don't specify `line-height` parameter for this text and browsers do it as they want. As you can see http://jsfiddle.net/87p5K/7/ here when I have set `line-height` for `140px` and thei it looks the same on all browsers. Also as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/87p5K/8/ I have shown `line-height` of your element and on IE it return `normal`. It means it depends of your `font-size`.

Comment: The screenshots in the question demonstrate a much more serious difference, but in the jsfiddle case, the issue is definitely `line-height`. When I test the HTML and CSS as a standalone document (to eliminate jsfiddle code effect), Chrome makes the “EXCITING” element 143px high, IE just 138px. Setting `line-height: 1.2` makes it 144px high in both browsers,

Comment: I'm using a web font in the screenshots. I think the type of font is the issue. Here is an updated jsfiddle using a different font. I can't get the text to center vertically with any line-height. http://jsfiddle.net/87p5K/9/

Sorry Mateusz, I don't think line-height is the issue.

Comment: As you can read on this article http://www.ehow.com/how_5482445_use-line-height-css.html some fonts are taller then the others. In your case you can only do it manually using padding it isn't best practise but here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/87p5K/10/

Comment: I was doing it manually with padding but I would have to use different values for different browsers which is not what I want to do since I want this site to be very portable and future proof. Ugh, might have to use images.

Answer (score 0):

Padding is handled differently in browsers due to different box models. You can use the css property "box-sizing" to set use one box model over another.

I'd suggest defining which box model to use in your css:

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/